# React native application buttons

Tags: javascript, react-native

I would like to make the buttons split into 2 buttons (left, right) so every button can be visible, I tried flex but it doesn't work.

It currently looks as follows.

[image]

> App.js

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import Buttons from './Buttons';


export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Buttons />
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        marginTop: 30,
        flex : 1
}});
```

> Buttons.js

```
export default function Buttons(){
    let alpha = Array.from(Array(26)).map((e, i) => i + 65);
    let alphabet = alpha.map((x) => String.fromCharCode(x));  
    let buttonList = [];
    
    for(let i=0;i<alphabet.length;i++){
      buttonList.push(<Button style={styles.box} key={i} title={alphabet[i]} />)
    }
    
    return buttonList;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you use a `FlatList` with two columns. Then set `flex: 1` to the container of each button. This is better for performance and does what you want.

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button, FlatList } from 'react-native';


export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(Array.from(Array(26)).map((e, i) => i + 65).map((x) => String.fromCharCode(x)))

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        numColumns={2}
        keyExtractor={item => item}
        renderItem={({item}) => {
      return (
        <View style={styles.box} ><Button key={item} title={item} /></View>
      );
    }}
/>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        marginTop: 30,
        flex : 1
    },
    box: {
      flex: 1,
    },
});
```

The above yields to the following.

[image]

It might be desired to have some space between the buttons. We can achieve this by just adding a margin.

```js
box: {
      flex: 1,
      margin: 5
    },
```

The above yields to the following.

[image]